# Printing with Zebra Printer

Tags: images, troubleshooting, printing

I am trying to print a bitmap image on a zebra printer (TLP-2844-Z) and it comes out incredibly blurry and faint but when I print it on a laser printer it looks fine.  Also, when I printer plain text to the zebra printer or the test page it comes out crystal clear.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the correct driver for that printer? Have you tried reinstalling it? Have you tried printing from a different application?

Comment: You may want to use a specific label printer application if this is for a business. Check out this roundup: http://bar-code-label-software-review.toptenreviews.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the dpi of the bitmap you are printing.  The TLP-2844-Z has a dpi of 203, where as the laser printer you are using is likely to be 600 or 1200 dpi, so you will see a difference in quality.  Using the correct driver will help.  Zebra has a lot of very similar models, and often it they have similar model names/numbers, so it can be hard to tell what is what.

Comment: The DPI must match exactly or the Zebra will dither the image to make it print, and as you've experienced, it's ugly.

Comment: I will check that out tomorrow and get back to everyone.

Comment: @ Nathan, did it work?